# How to convert type double to string iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring, double, velocity

I am calculating the velocity of an iPhone, and I need to know how to convert the variable calculatedSpeed which is type double to type string to display on a label.

Here is what I have in the header:

```
@interface myProject : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {

double calculatedSpeed; 
    UILabel *velocityLabel;
}
```

And here is what I have in the main:

```
-(void)speedLocation:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
double gpsSpeed = newLocation.speed;

if(oldLocation != nil)
{
    CLLocationDistance distanceChange = [newLocation getDistanceFrom:oldLocation];
    NSTimeInterval sinceLastUpdate = [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate:oldLocation.timestamp];
    calculatedSpeed = distanceChange / sinceLastUpdate;

    velocityLabel.text = calculatedSpeed;

}

}
```

Notice how I am trying to set velocityLabel to calculatedSpeed, which is a variable with the type double. So it naturally gives me the error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'setText:'.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
velocityLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", calculatedSpeed];
```

Comment: Possibly also helpful to say that the formatters accepted by NSString are the same as those accepted by printf, as documented in lots of places including http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/printf.html . So if you look up 'g' you'll see it's a "double" (ie, or float, per the C promotion rules) output in scientific or standard format.